# What does とする do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 人や荷物の移送を**商売とする**馬車輸送がそこかしこで見受けられるようになっている。

I don't understand what とする does in this sentence. Can someone explain it to me?

Thanks!

Comment: It's always a good idea to tell us what the sentence is from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とする here makes an attribute out of a noun 商売 "trade, business".

Literally meaning "making (transport of people and goods) a business", it corresponds in this context to English "**commercial** horse-drawn transport of goods and people"

Answer (score 0):

とする in this case means "to treat as; to use for."
It can be broken down into と "as/with" and する "to do."

> 人や荷物の移送を商売とする馬車輸送
>   Horse-drawn transport carriages that use the transportation of (stuff like) people and luggage for business.